# Error on Android class R

Tags: android

I don't know why, but ever I create new Android project this coming with error on Class R.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
```

On `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)` Eclipse show me a error

> R cannot be resolved to a variable

So, I try to use `import android.R;` but I get other error:

> activity_main cannot be resolved or is not a field

Why it happen? How I can resolve this issue? And why a New Eclipse project is already coming with error?

Thanks!

Comment: Don't import `android.R`, it will definitely not contain your xml layout. Do the xml layouts have anything highlighted in red? Did you try cleaning your project?

Comment: Most likely your own `R.java` is not correctly created, probably your project contains errors so check classes, xml files and clean your project. it should regenerate your `R.java`

Comment: just clean your project..

Comment: How I clean solution ??

Comment: are you using eclipse or netbeans?

Comment: @rochasdv, if you're using eclipse.. go to Project-> Clean or


if you're using netbeans.. go to Run->Clean and Build Main Project

Comment: Thanks, but not even works....I changed my default Eclipse IDE for the new Android SDK IDE, downloaded here: http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html

Comment: is it happen whenever you start a new project? if so, try to erase all eclipse and adt and download it again and then try to create a new project

Comment: Yes, ever when I start a new project.

Comment: I think you should install it again.. remove all the related files (but save projects that u need) and download it again from the developer.android site.. I installed it and it works for me.. 
maybe some files were corrupted when you download it.. so try it again.. and where you start a new project -> clean it and wait to see if the errors are gone
anyway you can even download eclipse juno and then install the android plugin..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks guys, I deleted my Eclipse and now I using the specific Eclise for Android, downloaded on http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html

This Eclipse is very good and my problem was solved.

Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 5):

Don't import android.R.  You need to import your own R file from the gen folder.  If your R file didn't get automatically generated for you, then check for errors in your layout XML files.